# How would one use databricks delta lake format with Kedro?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, kedro

We are using [kedro](http://kedro.readthedocs.io/) in our project. Normally, one can define datasets as such:

```
client_table:
  type: spark.SparkDataSet
  filepath: ${base_path_spark}/${env}/client_table
  file_format: parquet
  save_args:
    mode: overwrite
```

Now we're running on databricks and they offer many [optimisations](https://databricks.com/de/blog/2020/10/21/faster-sql-adaptive-query-execution-in-databricks.html) such as `autoOptimizeShuffle`. We are considering to make use of this to handle our 15TB+ datasets.

However, it's not clear to me how to use kedro with the databricks delta lake solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kedro now has a native dataset, see the docs here:
https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tools_integration/pyspark.html#spark-and-delta-lake-interaction

```yaml
temperature:
  type: spark.SparkDataSet
  filepath: data/01_raw/data.csv
  file_format: "csv"
  load_args:
    header: True
    inferSchema: True
  save_args:
    sep: '|'
    header: True

weather@spark:
  type: spark.SparkDataSet
  filepath: s3a://my_bucket/03_primary/weather
  file_format: "delta"
  save_args:
    mode: "overwrite"
    versionAsOf: 0

weather@delta:
  type: spark.DeltaTableDataSet
  filepath: s3a://my_bucket/03_primary/weather
```

Answer (score 2):

Its worked for us.

```
    client_table:
      type: kedro.contrib.io.pyspark.SparkDataSet
      filepath: ${base_path_spark}/${env}/client_table
      file_format: "delta"
      save_args:
        mode: overwrite
```